# F-test formula under robust standard error

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, f-test, robust-standard-error

I am attempting to write a program that will (among other things) use the F-test in multivariate regression under standard robust errors. I am having trouble finding a specific  formula for the F-statistic using robust errors.

I understand the purpose of robust errors. I simply need the modified formula for the F-statistic.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please note, not to be confused with testing the test for heteroskedasticity using the F-distribution. I'm talking about restricting a number of variables in the model under robust standard errors.

Answer (score 8):

In the linear regression model
$$\mathbf y = \mathbf X\beta + \mathbf u$$
with $K$ regressors and a sample of size $N$, if we have $q$ linear restrictions on the parameters that we want to test,

$$\mathbf R\beta = \mathbf r$$

where $\mathbf R$ is $q \times K$, then we have the Wald statistic

$$W= (\mathbf R\hat \beta - \mathbf r)'(\mathbf R \mathbf {\hat V} \mathbf R')^{-1}(\mathbf R\hat \beta - \mathbf r) \sim_{asymp.} \mathcal \chi^2_q$$

and where $\mathbf {\hat V}$ is the consistently estimated heteroskedasticity-robust asymptotic variance-covariance matrix of the estimator,

$$\mathbf {\hat V}=(\mathbf X'\mathbf X)^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \hat u_i^2\mathbf x_i'\mathbf x_i\right)(\mathbf X'\mathbf X)^{-1}$$
or

$$\mathbf {\hat V}=\frac {N}{N-K}(\mathbf X'\mathbf X)^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \hat u_i^2\mathbf x_i'\mathbf x_i\right)(\mathbf X'\mathbf X)^{-1}$$

(there is some evidence that this degrees-of-freedom correction improves finite-sample performance).

If we divide the statistic by $q$ we obtain an approximate $F$-statistic

$$W/q \sim_{approx}  F_{q, N-K}$$

but why add one more layer of approximation?

**ADDENDUM 2-8-2014**

The reason why we obtain an approximate $F$-statistic if we divide a chi-square by its degrees of freedom is because

$$\lim_{N-K \rightarrow \infty} qF_{q, N-K} = \chi^2_q$$

see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97091/limiting-distribution-of-y-nu-1x-is-chi-square-with-nu-1-degrees-of-freedo/97111#97111).

Comment: How do you prove that $W/q \sim^{approx} F_{q,(N-k)}$ ?  I trust this is correct, but I have never actually seen a proof.

Comment: @MichaelGmeiner Please follow the link in the Addendum.